# A Single Path Forward

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, knowledge

> A Boniface gives __________
>   A Bamberger exit __________
>   A Murietta heads __________
>   A Bergeret kicked one

The answer is a four word phrase.

Hint:

> 'Til death do us part

Hint 2:

> One name is different.

Hint 3:

> Bucket. Same as clue #1.

Length of blanks do not give an indication to the words that go there.

Hint 4:

> However, following the clues, there's a way of obtaining their lengths.

Final:

> If you're sure (or mostly sure) about the word lengths then it *might* help to reorder the lines (DESC).

Comment: Two old german dudes, a mexican robin hood, and a french painter,,,

Comment: I believe it has nothing to do with names but letters.

Comment: @John Yeah it makes a lot more sense now

Comment: @nikamed what makes you think that?

Comment: @Areeb Because the puzzle would be too knowledge related.

Comment: @nikamed I've seen puzzles that were a lot more obscure and knowledge based than this, I think it has to do with the people

Comment: @Areeb, it's as correct and incorrect as it was before.

Comment: @areeb, just a follow-up, you don't have the nationalities quite right.

Comment: @John i'm stuck there, I can't see how any other people would fit in

Comment: @Areeb, okay, well it doesn't look like many people are getting anywhere either. I've changed the tags, removing enigmatic and specifically labeling the puzzle with the pattern tag, so hopefully that helps, and lateral-thinking. The lateral-thinking tag is a little problematic, but I'll say that this puzzle has what I prefer to call 'turns'. But the hint tends to continually apply.

Comment: @areeb, new clue as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: @John, I did. Still looking :)

Comment: That didn't help me... :(

Comment: @GeraldPatriowski, I want this to be resolved. :)

Comment: @John huh, Bergeret kicked the bucket. That wouldn't be close to the phrase would it?

Comment: @Areeb, yep, seems that way.

Comment: @John Making it fit the clues seems a ot harder

Comment: @Areeb, have you established the relevance of hint #2 yet?

Comment: @John I'd guess it's Bamberger since there isn't any other Murietta or Boniface

Comment: @Areeb, ehhh, so I'd give you partial credit on that response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I have it. Based on the title, A Single Path Forward:

> Only one way out.

A Boniface gives

> way

A Bamberger exit

> only

A Murietta heads

> out

A Bergeret kicked

> one

Reordered, by descending date of

> death, whose years were alluded to by the number of letters (1944, 1863, 1853, 1853) you have:
> A Bamberger exit only (1944 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Bamberger)
> A Bergeret kicked one (1863 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Nolasque_Bergeret)
> A Boniface gives way (1853-DEC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Etienne_Boniface)
> A Murietta heads out (1853-JUL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joaquin_Murrieta)

Comment: Wow so there wasn't any need to look up dead people

Comment: @Areeb, not in the sense that you needed to know anything about the people. Just euphemisms for death. Maybe a better first hint would have been 'bit the dust' or 'pushing up daisies', etc.

Comment: @John oh well, it was a clever puzzle

Comment: @John I don't understand a bunch of this. How is there a way, as stated in Hint 4, to determine the lengths of the words? What does "exit only" mean...it's supposed to be a euphemism for death? "Heads out" means more leave the house than died. "Gives way" is borderline. How is one name different (hint 2)?

Comment: @DanRussell, the euphemisms are constrained to two words, so, kicking the bucket is simply 'kicked one'. Fully formed euphemisms would be better, but leaving that aside for the moment, the word lengths are determined by the year of their deaths. So, for the line that was given "A Bergeret kicked one", you can see that the letter count for each word is 1-8-6-3. If you google "Bergeret 1963" the correct person comes up. Finding a very famous Murietta, you'll see that he died in 1853, so the fourth word you're trying to find is 3 letters long. The others you need to find the name and the decade.

Comment: @DanRussell (continued), So, if you try to find a Bamberger who died in the 1940's, and a Boniface who died in the 1850's, you can easily find the correct year. So re-ordered, descending, you'd have something like "[blank-4] [one] [blank-3] [blank-3]". Gives way is not great, but exit only, and heads out are easy enough. At that point you'd have "only one [blank] out", which should be enough.If you were unable to see that the letter count equaled a year, it would definitely put you at a disadvantage, especially when the order helps

Comment: @John Okay. Just keep in mind for future puzzles that there's usually a bias when creating a puzzle: since you know the tricks/methods, it seems easier to you than it really is.  Consider leaving clues (in the original puzzle) to the steps needed to solve it.  As the original puzzle was written, it's very hard to know that word length matters, or death is important, or reordering the lines will be necessary.

Comment: @DanRussell, sending words or phrases through a program to get hex, binary, anagrams, or other clues is very common. Perhaps, counting letters was not obvious, but certainly easier than the aforementioned approaches. Nonetheless, with the "Til death do us part", people should've seen the final word lengths fairly easily. That leaves the matter of euphemisms. That I do concede (partially :) ), and I do concede that seeing them through other's eyes is important. Which is why I now create puzzles and then put them away and revisit later to see if I know what I was thinking.

Comment: @John I agree about the hex/binary/vigenere IF there's no clues to those as well.  If the "death do us part" part was important, consider making it part of the puzzle (or even the title!) rather than a hint [(see this)](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5008/21234).  And your statement *"with the "Til death do us part", people should've seen the final word lengths fairly easily"* is exactly what I mean about how things seem easier to you because you know the answer!  (Wasn't obvious to me at all...)

Comment: @DanRussell, In this case, the word lengths made putting clues in the puzzle difficult. I believe all the major hints were provided before the bounty was placed and "One name is different" is very strong as you know along with the pattern tag. If the simplicity of the line made the year "clear", e.g. 1-9-4-4, then constructing a line that provide's the hint within it, would necessarily require more words, more deconstruction and the year would then be further obfuscated. Your link, "Hints should be supplementary". The title wasn't supplementary, it was a virtual synonym for the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43369/discussion-between-dan-russell-and-john).

Answer (score 4):

A boniface gives:

> his life, He was killed by pagan tribes people 
>  > Saint Boniface

A Bamberger exit:

> Germany, because he was in exile 
>  > Ludwig Bamberger

A Murietta heads:

> to California, He went for the gold-rush
>  > Joaquin Murrieta

Comment: You have one component correct.

Comment: @John Would you tell me which one it is?

Comment: @Areeb: I think it's the third one, since it's the only one where you intepret the third word as a noun rather than a verb.

Comment: @Deusovi I suppose it could be that but I don't see how the others could be nouns. I'd wager it's the second one since it's the only place I mentioned.

Comment: @John thanks! I think I know which one is correct

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out the answer, but most of the blanks seem to be related to death, as hinted in Hints #1 and #3.

One can give

> His life

Kick

> The bucket

Head for

> The last round-up

I still haven't found the meaning of "exit ___" , what the names refer to, and how the lengths of the words can be obtained. The single path forward could be the one to the graveyard, where everyone ends

Comment: You're right about kicking the bucket, but that line is complete. Life is a good answer, but not the one that fits there (or anywhere). Knowing the lengths would help you there. Indeed, this puzzle is pretty morbid. (And only a single word goes in the slots). +1

Comment: To give up the ghost apparently means dying as well. I'll look into it.
Edit: Didn't see that a single word fitted. Thanks for the hints